# creating the named pipes

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I am killing a process that has a thread with named pipe server. After killing that process, I am trying to create a named pipe server with the same name. Program crashes. I am getting "all pipe instances are busy". How to resolve this?

Comment: can you please show your effort in code so we can help you

Comment: I disconnected the pipe server before killing the process. But I cannot create a named pipe server with the same name in a new process.

Comment: I once had a similar problem where the server was not able to re-create a pipe with clients still using it. I ended up placing the server's pipe creation into a separate AppDomain and unloading it, thus killing the pipe entirely.  Though that's probably a bit late for your situation...

Comment: Problem was solved. I was trying to create the named pipe in a new process and close the named pipe with same in another process simultaneously. Control in my new process reaches the line which tries to create the named pipe before closing the named pipe in the process that I am trying to kill. I fixed the issue.